# Creating 1 dict from tuple containing tuples of multiple dicts Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to implement a quicksort algorithm to sort a `dict` I give it into ascending order. I have been able to get it to sort the dicts but it returns a `tuple` that contains the sorted dicts but some are within another tuple for example this input:

```
sortDict({'jladf':4,'hi':1,'ping':9,'boo':2,'adlfa':1})
```

will return:

```
(({}, {'hi': 1, 'adlfa': 1}, {'boo': 2}), {'jladf': 4}, {'ping': 9})
```

and I'm not sure how to combine this output to one dict. If I need to include any more information please let me know thank you.

The code I'm using:

```
def sortDict(unsortedDict):
    less={}
    equal={}
    greater={}
    if len(unsortedDict)>1:
        pivotValue=unsortedDict[unsortedDict.keys()[0]]
        for k,v in unsortedDict.iteritems():
            if v<pivotValue:
                less[k]=v
            elif v>pivotValue:
                greater[k]=v
            elif v==pivotValue:
                equal[k]=v
        return sortDict(less),equal,sortDict(greater)
    else:
        return unsortedDict
```

Comment: You'll need to keep the results in an `OrderedDict`. With the builtin sort: `OrderedDict(sorted(t.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))`

Comment: what is x and t in this case and wouldnt using sorted render this entire function pointless?

Comment: `t` is your dictionary, `x` is each item passed from `t.items()`. Well, the point is to let you see that what you're trying to do already exists, not to render your function pointless.

Comment: I knew sorted existed however I thought it was slower than quicksort which is what I'm trying to implement

Comment: As a rule of thumb, builtins are always faster than algorithms implemented in python code. The overhead from the interpreter for every instruction is way too high to beat raw C++. The instructions required to resolve `unsortedDict[unsortedDict.keys()[0]]` are probably already very costly - fetch the `keys` method, run it, implicitly built a new `list` of keys, get a value from it, use that value to get something from `unsortedDict` again, then deallocate the list of keys.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer